# How can I save an array of Double in UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, double, userdefaults

How can I save an array of Double in `UserDefaults`?

How come my `UserDefaults` evaluate to nil?

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num")!)
if var o = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num") as? [Double] {
    o.insert(Double(self.slid), at: 0)
    print("opa \(o)")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "num")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(o, forKey: "num")
    if let z = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num") {
        print(z)
    }
} else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(self.slid), forKey: "num")
    if let z = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num") {
        print("kl \(z)")
    } else {
        print("nilo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the value initially as an array of double `[Double]` instead of just a single `Double`. Modify to the below line:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(self.slid), forKey: "num")
```

To:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([Double(self.slid)], forKey: "num")
```

Here is the complete code you'll need:

```
if var array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num") as? [Double] {
    array.insert(Double(self.slid), at: 0)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "num")
} else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set([Double(self.slid)], forKey: "num")
}
print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "num"))
```